# How to use Count in login?

Tags: vb.net, authentication

I wanted to make my login with a function Count but I got no idea how. What I want is when user type wrong username and password wrong for 3 times, the program will close down and show message.

```
 Dim i As Integer

    If txtUsername.Text = "username" Then
        If txtPassword.Text = "password" Then
            MessageBox.Show("I am KING!!")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Failed!!")
    End If

    If (i >= 3) Then
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Get Out")
    End
```

Please show me how to command this. Thank You

Comment: Do you have a database?  I am also going under the assumption that you are developing a desktop application.

Comment: No database at all. This is just a testing work for my college.

Comment: You can find my login system that uses a similar idea here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/mlogin.aspx
Basically, it counts a session variable for each login attempt. It goes as far as making the account inaccessible when that variable has been counted 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public i as integer = 0

Public Sub CheckLogin()
    If txtUsername.Text = "calvin" Then
        If txtPassword.Text = "calvin" Then
            MessageBox.Show("I am KING!!")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("I am Pig!!")
        i += 1 'Increment times by 1
    End If

    If (i >= 3) Then
        End
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not clear about the increment. Would the value of `i` not be reset after every postback? I used sessions on my system (which is actually a fair bit more sophisticated than this if I do say so myself).
Nevertheless, I do agree that the increment you added here should be what the OP is looking for. +1

Comment: "Public i As Integer = 0" is outside of block "Sub CheckLogin ()"
so when you call to "Sub CheckLogin ()" does not re-set the value to 0